# DIV height doesn't auto size properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, height

I have a plain Image wrapped in an Absolute DIV, all contained within a Relative DIV.  No margins, no padding, no floats.  The height and width on my Image containing DIV are set to auto to expand to the size of the Image.  Everything is fine in both FF and IE, but in Chrome, the Image acts as if it's containing Div's height was set to 100%, filling the vertical space of the outer container.

Any ideas?

Thanx,
Chris

Comment: First idea: recreate this on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had set the height/width to 100% on the Image itself.  FF and IE didn't carry that through to the outer DIV container, whereas Chrome did.